# Howto use matlab like operator in C++ with stl vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, operators

In matlab we can use the matlab operator as follows:

```
M=[1 2 3 4, 5 6 7 8, 9 10 11 12]
M[:,1] = M[:,2] + M[:,3]
```

to apply the same operation to all the rows of a matrix
I'am wondering if we can apply a same operation to set values to a range of values in `std::vector` as it's done with colon(:) matlab's operator. Indeed, I'm using a vector to store the matrix values.

```
vector<int> M;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C++ has no standard operation for that. You have to program it yourself or use a 3rd party matrix library

Comment: @JoachimPileborg interesting function that I did not know but that is not what I'm looking for; Thanks.

Comment: @tuxworker: How do you imagine an operation on a matrix without a loop on the elements?

Comment: SSE SIMD vectorization like stuff?

Comment: @Andrey Indeed, I asked for that because I'm being to proceed several times as I described with a big vector. So I'm looking for efficiency by avoiding to loop with for statement (for example) on the vector elements each time. I expected that there is a more efficient way to acces to a range of elements in the vector. Thanks –

Comment: @Acorbe I've not known what it is. But according to wikipedia definition it is what I want.

Comment: @tuxworker, basically you're allowed to operate on 4 `float`s or 2 `double`s at a time (Matlab also relies on this). Although, because it is very low level code to deal with, I would suggest the use of eigen (see answer) or other libraries.

Comment: @tuxworker: MATLAB internally does it with a loop, too. However, low-level optimizations, or something specific to your problem are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are C++ libraries that allow one to handle matrices pretty much as matlab does (allowing also for [**SIMD**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) vectorization); you may want to consider [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), for instance.

If you don't want to rely on external library you may want to consider [`std::valarray`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/) which has been explicitly thought for algebraic computations (with `valarray`s you may use [`std::slices`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/slice/) to extract submatrices as you need).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a "free" operator that takes `std::vector<int>` as parameters:

```
std::vector<int> operator +(const std::vector<int> &a, const std::vector<int> &b)
{
    std::vector<int> result(a); // Copy the 'a' operand.

    // The usual matrix addition is defined for two matrices of the same dimensions.
    if (a.size() == b.size())
    {
        // The sum of two matrices a and a, is computed by adding corresponding elements.
        for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < b.size(); ++b)
            // Add the values of the 'b' operand.
            result[i] += b[i];

        return result;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<int> b;

    // The copy constructor takes care of the assignement.
    std::vector<int> c(a + b);

    return 0;
}
```

The implementation of the `operator +` is quite naive, but is just an idea. Beware!, i've placed a ckeck before the add operation, if the check isn't passed a copy of the `a` operand is returned, i think that this will not be your desired behavior.

I've placed the operator in the same file of `main` but you can place it wherever you want as long as it is visible where the operation is performed.

Of course, you can define the operators you want in order to chain operations to achieve some more complex operations.

My maths concepts are quite old, but i hope it helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to `do the stuff`? That is the point of the question.

Comment: Sorry, i've misunderstood the question, my math concepts are quite old, but i'll try to help.